# Does $H^{\bullet}(G, \mathbb{Z})$ have a coalgebra structure?

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Here are two well-known facts:

1. Let $X$ be a topological space. We always have the *diagonal* map $\Delta :X\to X\times X$ and this induces a map $H^{\bullet}(X)\otimes H^{\bullet}(X) \simeq H^{\bullet}(X\times X )\to H^{\bullet}(X)$, which induces algebra structure on $H^{\bullet}(X)$. We call such multiplication as a cup product. (Let's forget about details about coefficients.)
2. Let $X$ be a topological *group*. Then the group operation map $X\times X\to X$ induces a comultiplication $H^{\bullet}(X) \to H^{\bullet}(X\times X)\simeq H^{\bullet}(X)\otimes H^{\bullet}(X)$ which is compatible with the cup product. Hence $H^{\bullet}(X)$ became a Hopf algebra.

Now here is my question: Let $X$ be a *group*, and we have a group operation map $X\times X\to X$ as before. Is it true that this induces a coalgebra structure on the group cohomology $H^{\bullet}(X,\mathbb{Z})\to H^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb{Z})\otimes H^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb{Z})$? If it is true, can we write down the map explicitly?

Comment: You need to assume either that $H^*(X;\Bbb Z)$ is torsion-free, or work with coefficients over the field, for the Kunneth map $H^*(X) \otimes H^*(X) \to H^*(X \times X)$ to be an isomorphism. Given that, yes, this gives a coalgebra (in fact, bialgebra) structure.

Comment: @MikeMiller Do you have any reference? Also, how can we obtain algebra structure? Is it just induced from the diagonal map $X\to X\times X$?

Comment: Yes, you described the algebra structure in the first paragraph! The various compatibility relations are induced by the diagrams you get in topological spaces. I suspect most algebraic topology books discuss this, but I first read about it in Hatcher.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks! I thought about this question since a group will be a natural candidate to have a map $X\times X\to X$ and no canonical map $X\to X\times X$, but there's always diagonal maps in any category with finite products...